# Why does Python mimetype guess XSL when passed an XML file?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, mime-types, file-extension

When passed a file with a mimetype `application/xml`, the Python std lib `mimetypes.guess_extension` method guesses an `.xsl` extension. This is actually [hard-coded in](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/mimetypes.py).

Why does it do that?

Comment: And `mimetypes.guess_type('foo.xml')` returns `application/xml` /0\.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there are a host of these, and the Python mimetypes module shouldn't generally be relied upon for these kinds of operations. See [the bug I filed in the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue29823) (and from there, the "superissue").